# Why is this FactoryGirl-created object visible in the test, but not in the view that is being tested?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, factory-bot

I'm using RSpec, FactoryGirl, and PhantomJS.

---

UPDATE:

I have verified that if I create this item in my `spec/support/login_macros.rb` `login_user` method, which I call below, the listing object is available in the view.

This seems like a FactoryGirl issue. Why can I create from a factory in that helper method, but can't inside the test itself? Here is the support method:

```
module LoginMacros
  def login_user(admin = false)

    myrepo = FactoryGirl.create(:repository, :myname)
    plan = FactoryGirl.create(:plan, name: "Test Multi", listing_limit: 5000, repositories_allowed: 5)

    user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)

    subscription = FactoryGirl.create(:subscription, user: user, plan: plan)
    user.add_repository(myrepo)
    listing = FactoryGirl.create(:listing, user: user, repository: myrepo)

    visit login_path
    fill_in 'Email', :with => user.email
    fill_in 'Password', :with => user.password
    click_button 'Go'
    user
  end
```

---

I have set `transactional_fixtures` to false in my `spec_helper.rb`. Here is my spec:

```
require "spec_helper"

describe "App Integration" do

  let!(:user) { login_user }
  let!(:myrepo) { user.repositories.where(name: "myrepo" ).first }

  it "lets a user add apps to a listing", js: true do
    listing = FactoryGirl.create(:listing, user: user, repository: myrepo)
    puts listing.inspect
    Capybara::Screenshot.screenshot_and_open_image
  end

end
```

Now here is the problem. See that `puts` line above? It prints out the object.

But in the screenshot, it's as if the object were ***never created***. Like magic!

And yet, both the User and the Repository objects ***are visible in the view***.

Also, I can go to a different view and see that ***Listing*** object. Just not on the main page of my application!

Why would that object be visible in one view and not the other? I'm just doing this on the main page:

```
<h3><%= Listing.count %></h3>
```

And it is always, always, always zero. Makes zero sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't look like you're ever calling `visit` inside of your test, so the page would always be blank. You need to call `visit root_path # (or whatever path that heading is on)` before saving the screenshot.

Comment: visit is called inside the login_user method. The correct screen is indeed coming up, but it just doesn't see that a Listing object has been created. It sees the User and Repository objects are in the database, but that's it.

Comment: Even though it's the same page, I needed to "revisit" the page since it was rendering what was visited before the object being created.

Answer (score 1):

`let!` blocks are invoked before `it` blocks. Since you're viewing the page in a `let!` block but creating the `listing` in the `it` block, the listing isn't created until after you've viewed the page.

Comment: How am I viewing the page in a ```let!``` block? The screenshot line is in an ```it``` block.

Comment: The screenshot saves whatever is currently being viewed to a file; it doesn't actually visit the page. The `visit` and `click_button` calls are what actually interact with the page.